# Can't connect to ISP

Tags: networking, internet

Since my IPS 'fixed' my internet connection, I can no longer connect to the internet on my laptop.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

(I can tether the laptop to my tablet via mobile data, but this is obviously not a long term option).

What info do you need and what options do I have? (I have no idea what info is relevant, as in 12 years of linux use, I've never encountered this problem before!)

Comment: 10 to one this sounds more like the ISP goofed up somewhere.  Without knowing what they fixed and Ubuntu connected before, would say to contact them again.  Reset/redo everything for connection(start as brand new connection) and check every wire connection, pull out wire/cable and push in again

Comment: I plugged the laptop into the router via the ethernet port. The internet worked, but when I tried to access the hub I got the following error message: https://ibb.co/x8rMw9C

Comment: Imagine that is the router IP address you used before.  Was router changed or did ISP do work/update it?  Google the router model and make to try to find other IP addresses that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the ISP and they sent a new router, everything is fine now.